# error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘subVec’ [-Werror=vla]

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I am getting error with `-Werror` flag, without `-Werror` flag no error. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

> Error: error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array
>   ‘subVec’[-Werror=vla] `std::vector<float> subVec[size];`

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> splitVector(std::vector<float> boxes)
{
  int n = 4;
  unsigned int size = (boxes.size() - 1) / n + 1;
  std::vector<float> subVec[size];
  cv::Rect rect;
  std::vector<cv::Rect> Bx;
  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
  {
    auto startItr = std::next(boxes.cbegin(), (k * n));
    auto endItr = std::next(boxes.cbegin(), ((k * n) + n));
    subVec[k].resize(n);
    if ((k * n) + n > boxes.size())
    {
      endItr = boxes.cend();
      subVec[k].resize(boxes.size() - (k * n));
    }
    std::copy(startItr, endItr, subVec[k].begin());
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    rect.x = subVec[i][1] * imgW;
    rect.y = subVec[i][0] * imgH;
    rect.width = subVec[i][3] * imgW;
    rect.height = subVec[i][2] * imgH;
    Bx.push_back(rect);
}
```

Comment: Change the line `std::vector<float> subVec[size];`  . Maybe you meant `std::vector<float> subVec(size);`. If not then it would help to describe what you are trying to do, and show the code that supposedly uses this variable

Comment: I hope now it will be more clear

Comment: ok , sounds like you want `std::vector< std::vector<float> > subVec(size);`

Comment: Great, thanks it works for me.

Comment: BTW the code causes undefined behaviour if `(k * n) + n > boxes.size()`,  the offset for `std::next` must be valid.

Comment: i did not quite get, can you tell what do you mean by the offset for `std::next`

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how to explain it differently, your code might go out of bounds with `std::next` and then you have the `if` statement after you already made the bad call to `next`

Answer (score 0):

In `std::vector<float> subVec[size];`  plain array with variable length is called [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which is not C++ feature. It is only legal in C.

Comment: is there anyway to do in c++?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` if performance is not critical.